# Fresh Xamarin Multiplatform Library fails to build (created from Visual Studio for Mac)

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I created a **Xamarin Multiplatform Library** using **Visual Studio for Mac**.

Then I just built the **MyProject.NuGet** project without any change and it fails.

When looking into the error, it shows,

`Cannot create a package that has no dependencies nor content.`

and also there were these warnings,

```
warning : The referenced project 'MyProject.Android' does not exist.
warning : The referenced project 'MyProject.iOS' does not exist.
```

but the **MyProject.Android** and **MyProject.iOS** are existing in the solution and they are having reference links in the **MyProject.NuGet** project too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the **.NuGet** project, open the *References*, then delete the **iOS** and **Android** project references.

  [image]
- Save the solution.
- Re-add the **iOS** and **Android** projects as project references to the **.NuGet** project.

  [image]
- Try building the **.NuGet** project now!

**NOTE:** Make sure the changes update in the **.NuGet.csproj** file

The project reference should have changed from,

```
<ProjectReference Include="MyProject.iOS">
  ...
</ProjectReference>
<ProjectReference Include="MyProject.Android">
  ...
</ProjectReference>
```

to

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.iOS\MyProject.iOS.csproj">
  ...
</ProjectReference>
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Android\MyProject.Android.csproj">
  ...
</ProjectReference>
```

in the **MyProject.NuGet.csproj** file

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Please do not forget to mark it as answer after three days, it will help others who have similar issue.